# C# : Whats a smart way to call a random constructor from a known amount of constructors?

Tags: c#, constructor

In my game I have different enemies. When I create a dungeon, I want the game to randomly decide which enemy to put in from of the player. Each enemy is created with his own constructor, For example:

```
Ogre Ogre1 = new Ogre(level 1);
```

I call the fight against the enemy with a Method I defined elsewhere

```
fight(enemy);
```

Now I know I can call a random constructor by doing something like this:

```
int i = new Random.Next(1,5)
```

and then this:

```
if (i= 1)
{Ogre Ogre1 = new Ogre(level 1);
Fight(Ogre1);
}

else if (i=2)
{ Skeleton Skeleton 1 = new Skeleton (level 1);
....
```

but, assuming I eventually will have quite a few enemies, this seems quite tedious.
Is there a smarter way to do this, for example, can I store the possible enemies in a List and then call a constructor from the list?

**Edit**: The Answer below seems to give me exactly what I need! It strangely only works if I type out the lambda expression, if I try to directly implement the solution:

```
    static Func<int, Enemy>[] EnemyFactory = new[] 
    {
        (level) => (Enemy) new Ogre(level),
        (level) => (Enemy) new Skeleton(level)
    };
```

I get the Error Code CS0826 No best type found for implicitly-typed array.

But if I type out the lambda function it suddenly works!

```
        static Func<int, Enemy>[] EnemyFactory = new Func<int, Enemy>[] 
    {
        (level) => (Enemy) new Ogre(level),
        (level) => (Enemy) new Skeleton(level)
    };
```

Comment: https://dev.to/gary_woodfine/how-to-use-factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-3ia3
In general you want a factory to create your enemies and from there on you can make that as complicated as you need.

Comment: Sounds like an x-y-problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an array of "enemy factories" of type `Func<IEnemy>` and pick a random factory from that array.

Here is a skeleton of a potential implementation:

```
interface IEnemy ...
class Ogre : IEnemy ...
class Skeleton : IEnemy ...

static Func<IEnemy>[] EnemyFactory = new Func<IEnemy>[] {
    () => (IEnemy)new Ogre()
,   () => (IEnemy)new Skeleton()
,   ...
};
```

If you are passing arguments to your constructors, they either need to be the same, or you need to pass a "superset" of all of them to your functors. For example, if you need to pass an object of type `Level` to all constructors, the change would look as follows:

```
static Func<Level,IEnemy>[] EnemyFactory = new Func<Level,IEnemy>[] {
    (level) => (IEnemy)new Ogre(level)
,   (level) => (IEnemy)new Skeleton(level)
,   ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergey! It strangely only works for me if I type out the lambda function as shown in my Edit, could you have a look at this and tell me what is wrong with my first implementation?

Comment: @Max I guess C# compiler isn't strict enough to derive the common type from function definitions. It would need to propagate the type from the declaration of the `EnemyFactory` into its member definitions, which C# standard does not allow, at least at this time.